# NoReverseMatch at /posts/ Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use slug as url in post detail. But this gives me error like this
.It says error is realted to posts.view.detail when my database is empty. but after adding few posts from admin interface i get error something like this

What is wrong here?

> NoReverseMatch at /posts/
>   Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P[^/]+)/$']
>
> posts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    #filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    # return "%s/%s.%s" %(instance.id,instance.id, extension)
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.id, filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, 
    null=True, 
    blank = True, 
    width_field="width_field", 
    height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
        #return "/posts/%s/" %(self.id)
    class Meta: 
        ordering: ["-timestamp", "-updated"]
def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)
pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Post)
```

> posts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    posts_create,
    posts_delete,
    posts_detail,
    posts_list,
    posts_update
    )

app_name = "posts"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", posts_list, name="list"),
    path("<slug>/", posts_detail, name="detail"),
    path("create/", posts_create, name="create"),
    path("<slug>/edit/", posts_update, name="update"),
    path("<slug:slug>/delete/", posts_delete, name="delete"),

]
```

> posts/view.py

```
def posts_detail(request, slug=None):
    #instance = Post.objects.get(id=1)
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)

def posts_list(request):
    queryset_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 5)
    page_request_var= "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try: 
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage: 
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    #contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "title": "List",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)
```

> templates/post_detail.html

```
{%extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %} {{instance.title}} {%endblock head %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    {% if instance.image %}
    <img src="{{instance.image.url}}" class="img-responsive"/>
    {% endif %}
<h1>{{title}}<small>{{instance.timestamp}}</small></h1>
    {{instance.content}}<br/>
</div>
{%endblock content %}
```

> post_list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content %}
    <h1>{{title}} <small>{% if instance.draft %}<span style="color: 'red';">Draft{{instance.publish}}</span>{% endif %}</small></h1>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
    <div>
    <!-- {% url 'posts:detail' id=obj.id %} -->
    <a href="{{obj.get_absolute_url}}">{{obj.title}}</a><br/>
    {{obj.publish}}<br/>
    {{obj.updated}}<br/>
    {{obj.content|linebreaks|truncatechars:120}}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for contact in contacts %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ contact.full_name|upper }}<br>
    {% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if object_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?{{page_request_var}}={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ object_list.number }} of {{ query_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if object_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?{{page_request_var}}={{ object_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

{%endblock content %}
```

Comment: can you share the template code from which you getting this error?

Comment: @shekhar i have updated my question with template have a look.

Comment: your other links are working? like edit and delete

Comment: path('<slug:slug>/', posts_detail, name='detail')

Comment: try this at your urls, may be your your view was not able to identify the slug

Comment: Shown code does not match given error message.

Comment: can you tell by looking into terminal that where the error pointing, I mean views or templates

Comment: @shekhar i did tried path('<slug:slug'>)  it's still not working.

Comment: @IvanStarostin  then which code you want to see ??

Comment: @shekhar none of the url is working.

Comment: The code throwing this error message. It does not use `slug` it uses `id`. There are no `reverse` calls passing `id` as argument here, in the shown code.

Comment: @IvanStarostin i did change id to slug in get_absolute_url function

Comment: @IvanStarostin  what do you suggest ?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I don't know what is problem here but i used url instead of path in urls.py file and now its working.

Comment: @IvanStarostin But it only work if if i have no posts in database . I don't know why

Comment: When this error occurs, I mean that when you call a view which view is throwing this error

Comment: An can you also show the line in your post list template which calling the detail view

Comment: @shekhar post_list view is throwing this error

Comment: @shekhar post_create is working fine

Comment: @shekhar only post_list is not working everything else is working fine .

Comment: @shekhar i have added post_list view have a look at it.

Comment: Html code also which contains the <a> of detail view

Comment: @shekhar added them  have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188998/discussion-between-shekhar-and-aditya-kumar).